# Avoid timeout when selecting more properties with Sparql from Wikidata

Tags: sparql, wikidata, wikidata-query-service

I'm trying to write a query where I find all musicians and their relatives, children, spouses, fathers and mothers from Wikidata, that are still alive:

Here's the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription ?birthDate ?positionHeld WHERE {
  {
    SELECT ?item WHERE {
      {
        ?item wdt:P106 wd:Q639669. 
        ?item wdt:P27 wd:Q43.
      }
      FILTER(NOT EXISTS { ?item (wdt:P570|wdt:P509|wdt:P20) ?o. })
    }
  }
  UNION
  {
    SELECT ?item WHERE {
      {
        ?parent wdt:P106 wd:Q639669.
        ?parent wdt:P27 wd:Q43.
      }
      OPTIONAL { ?parent wdt:P40 ?item. }
    }
  }
  UNION
  {
    SELECT ?item WHERE {
      {
        ?parent wdt:P106 wd:Q639669.
        ?parent wdt:P27 wd:Q43.
      }
      OPTIONAL { ?parent wdt:P22 ?item. }
    }
  }
  UNION
  {
    SELECT ?item WHERE {
      {
        ?parent wdt:P106 wd:Q639669.
        ?parent wdt:P27 wd:Q43.
      }
      OPTIONAL { ?parent wdt:P26 ?item. }
    }
  }
  UNION
  {
    SELECT ?item WHERE {
      {
        ?parent wdt:P106 wd:Q639669.
        ?parent wdt:P27 wd:Q43.
      }
      OPTIONAL { ?parent wdt:P25 ?item. }
    }
  }
  UNION
  {
    SELECT ?item WHERE {
      {
        ?parent wdt:P106 wd:Q82955.
        ?parent wdt:P27 wd:Q43.
      }
      OPTIONAL { ?parent wdt:P1038 ?item. }
    }
  }
  OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P569 ?birthDate. }
  OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P39 ?positionHeld. }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE]". }
}
```

This query times out. When I remove

```
OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P569 ?birthDate. }
OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P569 ?positionHeld. }
```

and stop selecting `?birthDate` and `?positionHeld` it works. Adding `FILTER(NOT EXISTS { ?parent (wdt:P570|wdt:P509|wdt:P20) ?o. })` to filter only relatives that are still alive to subqueries also generates a timeout. So:

1. How can I select `?birthDate` and `?positionHeld` without timing out?
2. How do I filter out relatives that have passed out?

Comment: is there a reason for all those subqueries fetching the relatives? Also, the last subquery does fetch politicians, which I guess is wrong. A simplified query would be

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription ?birthDate ?positionHeld WHERE {
  {
    SELECT ?item WHERE {
      {
        ?item wdt:P106 wd:Q639669. 
        ?item wdt:P27 wd:Q43.
      }
      FILTER(NOT EXISTS { ?item (wdt:P570|wdt:P509|wdt:P20) ?o. })
    }
  }
  UNION`

Comment: `{
    SELECT ?item WHERE {
      
        ?parent wdt:P106 wd:Q639669.
        ?parent wdt:P27 wd:Q43.
        ?parent wdt:P40|wdt:P22|wdt:P26|wdt:P25|wdt:P1038 ?item. 
        FILTER(NOT EXISTS { ?item (wdt:P570|wdt:P509|wdt:P20) ?o. })
    }
  }
  OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P569 ?birthDate. }
  OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P39 ?positionHeld. }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE]". }
}`

Comment: It could even be more simplified if needed.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription ?birthDate ?positionHeld WHERE {
  {
    ?item wdt:P106 wd:Q639669;
      wdt:P27 wd:Q43.
  }
  UNION
  {
    ?parent wdt:P106 wd:Q639669;
      wdt:P27 wd:Q43;
      (wdt:P40|wdt:P22|wdt:P26|wdt:P25|wdt:P1038) ?item.
  }
  FILTER(NOT EXISTS { ?item (wdt:P570|wdt:P509|wdt:P20) ?o. })
  OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P569 ?birthDate. }
  OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P39 ?positionHeld. }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE]". }
}`

Comment: @UninformedUser I see, I tweaked your last just to include living musicians and their living relatives, and it worked very well. If you could post it as an answer, happy to accept.

Comment: @HasanCanSaral: Feel free to post the tweaked query as an answer and accept it.